# LoadRunner_How to pass a huge json response from first action into the request body of second action?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am new to loadrunner and desperately need some help with my script. I need to pass a json response captured (from the response of action1) as a request for action 2.

I have captured the response of Action1 using below:

> web_reg_save_param_json(
> "ParamName=OfferAdditionalAttributes_Param",
> "QueryString=$.offers[0].offerAdditionalAttributes",
> "NotFound=warning",
> "SelectAll=Yes",
> SEARCH_FILTERS,
> "Scope=BODY",
> "IgnoreRedirections=Yes",
> "RequestUrl=https:blabla.com",
> LAST);

The response captured for OfferAdditionalAttributes_Param is very big something like:

"OfferAdditionalAttributes_Param_1 = [{"name":"ACCT_NUM_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"AMOUNT_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"BL_DAYS_ACCEPT","value":"90","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"BL_DAYS_REJECT","value":"90","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"CCAPS_REF_NUM_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"CRTV_END_DT_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"EffectiveDate","value":"2018-07-01T00:00:00","valueDataType":"datetime"},{"name":"ExpirationDate","value":"2099-12-31T00:00:00","valueDataType":"datetime"},{"name":"ExpirationDuration","value":"0","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"FINALSCORE","value":"80","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"FIRST_NAME_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"INCENTIVE_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"IVR_TYPE","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"LAST_NAME_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"LIMIT_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"MarketerScore","value":"80","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"MAX_NUM_PRESENT","value":"10","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"MOB_PROD_CATG","value":"1","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"MRKTG_RATE_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"Offer_Group","value":"NR_XSELL","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"OFFERDESC_FR","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"OMT_OFFER_CODE","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"PRODUCT_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"PROPOSED_LIMIT_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"PROPOSED_RATE_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RATE_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RELEVANT_DATE_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RELEVANT_ID","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RELEVANT_NAME","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RELEVANT_NAME_IND","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RELEVANT_NUM","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_10_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_1_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_2_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_3_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_4_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_5_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_6_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_7_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_8_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RESERVED_9_","value":"N/A","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"RTLearningMode","value":"3","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"RTLearningModelID","value":"0","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"RTSelectionMethod","value":"3","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"SOLUTION_CODE","value":"EDB_SBA_XSLL_1","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"TOPIC_DISCUSSION","value":"1","valueDataType":"string"},{"name":"UACIInteractionPointID","value":"24","valueDataType":"numeric"},{"name":"UACIInteractionPointName","value":"ATMMain_IP","valueDataType":"string"}]"

I want to pass the value of OfferAdditionalAttributes_Param into the request body for action2. Please advice how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a string.   Insert it into the location as required for the next request which needs it.